# What is this called in a Javascript Variable function?

Tags: javascript

What is the last line of code called? I know there is a Javascript variable saveFile being used as a function, passing the parameter "file", but I've never seen the last line of code used before.

```
var saveFile = function (file) {

    // do the stuff   

} (typeof self !== "undefined" && self || typeof window !== "undefined" && window || this.content);
```

Comment: @JohnColeman This particular idiom in JavaScript programming does have a name, and it's called a "self-executing anonymous function".

Comment: @Dai -- but you are making a guess as to what OP means by "this". For all anyone knows, perhaps they are confused by `typeof` or the use of the logical operators.

Comment: @JohnColeman The OP wrote "What is the last line of code called?" - I assume they're asking about the `} ( stuff );` syntax which is a hallmark of a SEAF.

Comment: @Dai You are probably right. (+1) for a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this into multiple steps:

1. You are creating a [function expression](https://javascript.info/function-expressions-arrows) and assigning the value to a variable called `saveFile` your function defines one parameter `file`:

   `var saveFile = function (file) {}`
2. Your function gets executed immediately after creation and you pass an `argument`:

   `var saveFile = function (file) {
       // do the stuff
    } (typeof self !== "undefined" && self || typeof window !== "undefined" && window || this.content);`
3. Your argument value depends on a [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

   `(typeof self !== "undefined" && self || typeof window !== "undefined" && window || this.content);`

Edit: Remember this, `functions` are first class objects in JavaScript, this simple means that you can do things like passing functions as arguments, declaring a function an assign it to a variable, add functions as values of objects, arrays and even return a function as a value.

Answer (score 3):

[It's a self-executing anonymous function](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/) - with a return value.

> I know there is a Javascript variable saveFile being used as a function, passing the parameter "file", but I've never seen the last line of code used before.

This is *not* what is happening. `saveFile` is *not* the function - it's a variable that's assigned a value that is returned from that function.

Here's what the engine does when it runs that code:

1. Define the anonymous function.
2. The anonymous function is immediately followed by parenthesis which means the anonymous function should be invoked immediately.
3. The expression `typeof self !== "undefined" && self || typeof window !== "undefined" && window || this.content` is evaluated and the resulting value is used as the argument for the `file` parameter for the anonymous function.
4. The anonymous function runs its code and returns a value.
5. That return value is then stored in `saveFile`.

It's equivalent to doing this:

```
function anonymous_function( file ) {
    // do the stuff
}

var fileArg = typeof self !== "undefined" && self || typeof window !== "undefined" && window || this.content;

var saveFile = anonymous_function( fileArg );
```

Comment: Great answer Dai!, just one comment I believe `anonymous_function` is a named function (A function declaration).

Comment: @ricardoorellana In OP's posted code, it's an anoynmous function. I posted code to show equivalent code **if the function was a named function** to make it easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it! @Dai